# How to repeat an image like css in lua?

Tags: lua, roblox

https://gyazo.com/d0d0bab65c0a7060972988a5e73c7959

That was achieved by the this:

```
local x = script.Parent.Smile
local y = script.Parent.Smile2

while true do

    x:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0, 0, 1, 0))
    y:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0, 0, 1, 0))
wait(.1)
    x.Position = y.Position + UDim2.new(0, 0, -1, 0)
    y.Position = UDim2.new(0, 0, 0, 0)    

end
```

I was wondering if there was a better way to do it and make it smoother(slower)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to look as if it endlessly descends, try adding a "Linear" parameter to your tweens. It will keep the tween constant in speed. For example:

```
local x = script.Parent.Smile
local y = script.Parent.Smile2

while true do

    x:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0, 0, 1, 0),"Out","Linear",0.1)
    y:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0, 0, 1, 0),"Out","Linear",0.1)
wait(.105) -- making sure to tween again after 0.1 seconds, the 0.105 safely accounts for any latency in the game
    x.Position = y.Position + UDim2.new(0, 0, -1, 0)
    y.Position = UDim2.new(0, 0, 0, 0)    

end
```

Try that script above, if it doesn't work you can blame me for it